Strange behaviour while creating an html file
I discovered a weird behaviour in nodejs in conjunction with nuxt.
When I try to create an html file at a server event handler, it will always results in a complete rerendering of my page, which shouldn't happen. I would expect just the fetch response and nothing more. Which I get anytime, when NOT creating an html file. I can create ANY OTHER file type and everything works as expected. Just html files will result in that behaviour. Does anyone has any idea what is happening here?
I created a minimal demo repo.
Just hit Create normal File and you will see, a text file is created in your folder and no page reload will occur. Try Create HTML File and you will probably see, that the html file is created as well, but a page reload will occur.
What is going on here?
